# flutter : change the cursor location to End of text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

According this [tutorial](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/styling-parts-of-a-textfield/2021/101326/) a have created a custom TextEditController.

In my textEdit controller I added this text : @tst. When I added this text a list appeasers and user can select one string from suggestion list.

And Finally I replace selected string with `@tst` . But the problem is here ?

The cursor located the first of Text:

[image]

I added this function end of my method:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000), () {
  print("=====>last");
  textEditCtl.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
      TextPosition(offset: textEditCtl.text.length));
});
```

but the cursor location not changed?

```
 void replaceCities() {
    
    var words = textEditCtl.text;
    final pattern = chunkString(words);
    final lastWord = words.substring(0, words.lastIndexOf(pattern));
    words = lastWord + '@' + selectedCities[0];
    textEditCtl.text = words;
    // textEditCtl.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
    //     TextPosition(offset: textEditCtl.text.length));
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000), () {
      print("=====>last");
      textEditCtl.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: textEditCtl.text.length));
    });
    selectedCities.clear();
  }
```

How can I change the cursor location to End of text?

I also Overrided this method in custom Controller:

```
 @override
  set text(String newText) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      text: newText,
      selection: TextSelection(
          baseOffset: newText.length, extentOffset: newText.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );

    selection =
        TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newText.length));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first assign value to text property of controller then you can do this.

```
textEditCtl.text = someString;
textEditCtl.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: textEditCtl.text.length));
```

Comment: I do that `    words = lastWord + '@' + selectedCities[0];
    textEditCtl.text = words;`  @HardikMehta

Comment: you can also try this one : final val = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: textEditCtl.text.length); 
 textEditCtl.selection = val;

Comment: I changed to this https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cfBbNQSDCg/ but no change @@HardikMehta

Comment: can you try by onChanged() of textfiled.  final val = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: textEditCtl.text.length); textEditCtl.selection = val;

Comment: I do but still, curser goes at the first of text . But when I delete the text , delete started from end of text but just curser is at the first od text @HardikMehta

Comment: can you show code for StyleableTextFieldController ?

Comment: This is https://github.com/flutter-clutter/flutter-stylable-text-field/blob/master/lib/stylable_text_field_controller.dart @HardikMehta